# Updating mysql table column based on value

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table with 7 column: `sun`,`mon`,`tue`, etc...

I have a row with all 0, and I need to update columns using `dayofWeek(now())`.

I need to update `sun=1` if functions return 1, `mon=1` if function returns 2, etc.

Comment: Okay.  I have supposed.  Now what?

Comment: I haven't even supposed, as I can't parse the third "i have" clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET
  sun=(dayofWeek(now()) = 1),
  mon=(dayofWeek(now()) = 2),
  tue=(dayofWeek(now()) = 3),
  ...
WHERE
  id=something
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a22c/1).

If you don't want to change your actual value, you could use something like this:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET
  sun=CASE WHEN dayofWeek(now()) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE sun END,
  mon=CASE WHEN dayofWeek(now()) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE mon END,
  tue=CASE WHEN dayofWeek(now()) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE tue END,
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks  but my main motive for the question is to get something like that select @day=dayofWeek(now()) and then can we have something like update case (@day==1) then set sun=1 case (@day==2) then set mon=2

Comment: @AshishMohan if I understand correctly, my second query should be what you need, just change the `...THEN 1 ELSE...` to `THEN 2...`, `THEN 3...`, etc. it will update the column of the current day, and it will leave all others columns unchanged